# Adding namespaces to root element of xml using jaxb

Tags: jaxb, xsd, xml-namespaces

I am creating an xml file whose root elemenet structure shuould be like:

```
   <RootElement xmlns="http://www.mysite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mysite.com/abc.xsd">
```

i created package-info.java class but i can get only one namespace by writing this code:

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://www.mysite.com",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package myproject.myapp;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Any idea?

Comment: schemaLocation should be pairs of `"{namespace} {schema uri}"` : `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com http://www.example.com/abc.xsd"`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Below is some demo code that will produce the XML you are looking for.  You can use the `Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION` property to specify the `schemaLocation` this will cause the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace to be automatically declared.

**Demo**

```
package myproject.myapp;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootElement.class);

        RootElement rootElement = new RootElement();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.mysite.com/abc.xsd");
        marshaller.marshal(rootElement, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RootElement xmlns="http://www.mysite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mysite.com/abc.xsd"/>
```

**package-info**

This is the `package-info` class from your question.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.mysite.com",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package myproject.myapp;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**RootElement**

Below is a simplified version of your domain model:

```
package myproject.myapp;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement")
public class RootElement {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the older Jaxb you can specify additional namespaces using `@XmlSeeAlso` and in the newer Jaxb you can use `@XmlNs` in package-info.java see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63559294/447503