# Add namespace prefix to only root elements?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, moxy

I have a XSD from which I generate my Java classes using `xjc`.

**XSD:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://example.com/xml/protocols"
    xmlns:abc="http://example.com/xml/protocols" elementFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="student">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <!-- Inherit common attributes from Regular Type -->
                <xs:extension base="abc:regular">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <!-- Resource Specific Attributes -->
                        <xs:element name="name" type="abc:name" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="URI" type="abc:listOfURIs" />

                        <xs:element name="content" type="abc:content" />


            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

**Student.java:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "eventNotificationCriteria",
    "notificationURI",
    "notificationContentType"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
public class Student
    extends Regular
{

    protected Name name;
    @XmlList
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> URI;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected BigInteger content;
.........
}
```

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="abc", 
                  namespaceURI="http://example.com/xml/protocols")}
)
package package.com;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

I marshall this object to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<abc:student xmlns:abc="http://www.example.com/xml/protocols">
    <name>
        <firstname>Jack</firstname>
    </name
    <URI>http://192.168.100.213:8090/S0</URI>
    <content>1</content>
</abc:student>
```

Here I want only my root elements to have **abc prefix** (abc:student).

I marshal like:

```
  marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<Student>(new QName("http://example.com/xml/protocols", "student", "abc"), Student.class, (Student)object), outputStream);
```

So I add `abc` prefix to my element.

However when I unmarshall I get exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.example.com/xml/protocols", local:"student"). Expected elements are <{}student>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:238)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1048)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:846)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:775)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:628)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:175)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
```

I know this exception is getting thrown as it's expecting an element without abc prefix (`abc:student`).

So if I add **namespace** inside `@XmlRootElement` like:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "student", namespace="http://example.com/xml/protocols")
    public class Student
        extends Regular{

}
```

This exception is not thrown. Now I have many such model classes all in same package. I want to add **namespace** in `@XmlRootElement` in all these.

I don't want to edit my so many classes manually.

Is there a way to add namespace to all `@XmlRootElements` in a package ??

Or am I doing something wrong ??

**How to add a prefix to only root elements ??**
If I add namespace in **package-info**, all elements get prefix **abc** which I don't want.

```
@XmlSchema(
        elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        namespace="http://example.com/xml/protocols"  
        xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="abc", 
                      namespaceURI="http://example.com/xml/protocols")}
    )
```

Comment: See if this helps: [**Adding namespaces to root element of xml using jaxb**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979762/adding-namespaces-to-root-element-of-xml-using-jaxb)

Comment: @kjhughes: This just add `xmlns:schemaLocation` to root element. I want a prefix to root element like `<prefix:rootelement xmlns:prefix="..."> </prefix:rootelement>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are unclear about the [XML namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). The element `<student>` is defined in `default namespace` as per your `xsd`, where as the child elements in `abc:namespace`. But if you add `namespace` in the `@XMLRootElement` then it means you are overwriting the xsd and the corresponding JAXB class is no more valid against the xsd.

So if you want to add namespace `abc` only to `<student>`, you can add it in xsd as follows

```
 <xs:element name="abc:student">
```

and rest of them in `defaultnamespace`.

```
   <xs:element name="abc:student">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <!-- Inherit common attributes from Regular Type -->
                <xs:extension base="regular">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <!-- Resource Specific Attributes -->
                        <xs:element name="name" type="name" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="URI" type="listOfURIs" />

                        <xs:element name="content" type="content" />


            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: When I generate XML from this XSD in eclipse (Right Click--->generate XML), I get the desried XML with `<abc:student></abc:student>`, but why is this not the case with first generating JAXB classes and then marshalling ??

Comment: It should, you will have to first generate from "this" xsd and marshall it. Post the JAXB to verify.

Comment: Sorry there was typo (*the not this). I meant from my XSD (not the one you wrote). So from my XSD I get the `<abc:student>` when (Right Click--->generate XML)but this is not the case with first generating JAXB classes and then marshalling. Any idea?

Comment: When I try what you wrote: I get `s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'name' in element 'element'. Recorded reason: cvc-
 datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'abc:subscription' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.`

Comment: your intention is not clear to me. And I noticed you have default `<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` which is not what you want. You will have first fix the `xsd` properly with what elements you want in what `namespace`. Are you to trying to declare `abc namespace` for this schema or you are referring `abc namespace` from another schema.