# How to move xmlns:xs and xmlns:xsi to Root Element with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to generate XML files from XSD generated Java Classes.

Some of the fields in those Java Classes as `Object` instead of any concrete type, and thus warrant a `xsi:type` attribute in the generated XML file, which is fine.

What is NOT fine though is that along with that `xsi:type`, the full namespace definition is added (`xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`), and makes the XML very unreadable.

To sum it up, here is what I generate now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns:RootTag xmlns:ns="https://example.com">
    <ns:SomeObjectField xsi:type="xs:boolean" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</ns:SomeObjectField>
    <ns:SomeOtherObjectField xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Some other value</ns:SomePtherObjectField>
</ns:RootTag>
```

And this is what I would like to generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns:RootTag xmlns:ns="https://example.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns:SomeObjectField xsi:type="xs:boolean">true</ns:SomeObjectField>
    <ns:SomeOtherObjectField xsi:type="xs:string">Some other value</ns:SomePtherObjectField>
</ns:RootTag>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The solution assuming you are using the **marshaller** of the **JAXBContext**, you can set a property for your namespace or schema location property. In my case I needed a noSchemaLocation:

```
 jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "facturaComputarizadaEstandar.xsd");
```

You might need to set a different property for your specific case.

Comment: An empty `xsi:schemaLocation` should also do: `marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "");`

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly declare xsi in `package-info.java`:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        xmlns = {
            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(
                    prefix = "ns",
                    namespaceURI = "https://example.com"),
            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(
                    prefix = "xsi",
                    namespaceURI = javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI) },
        namespace = "https://example.com",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package org.foo;
```

- prefix = "ns": `<ns:RootTag>`
- prefix = "": `<RootTag>`

See [JAXBContextImpl.xmlNsSet](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/blob/ae80415110ec0711d8854f7aa8e59872e580515c/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jaxb/runtime/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.java#L281)

[NamespaceContextImpl.declareNsUri()](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/blob/ae80415110ec0711d8854f7aa8e59872e580515c/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jaxb/runtime/v2/runtime/XMLSerializer.java#L864)

[JAXBContextImpl.schemaLocation](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/blob/ae80415110ec0711d8854f7aa8e59872e580515c/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jaxb/runtime/v2/runtime/XMLSerializer.java#L899)

In the older jaxb implementation 2.1 the `@XmlNs` is only used when generating a schema file and as a workaround you can add:

```
@XmlSeeAlso(DummyTypeWithinXsi.class)
public class RootTag ...
...
@XmlRootElement(namespace = javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI)
public class DummyTypeWithinXsi {
}
```

_