# Adding namespace dynamically for JAXB classes

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<roots xmlns="http://www.test.com/test/rest/v1">
   <root>
      <name>james</name>
   </root>
</roots>
```

I want to generate the JAXB classes for the above xml and add the name space (`xmlns="http://www.test.com/test/rest/v1"`) dynamically while marshaling. I could able to generate the JAXB classes, but not able to add the namespace dynamically. I tried with the following code, but it's not working. Any idea on how to do that?

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.test");

XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(inputSchema);
xmlStreamWriter.setPrefix("xmlns", "http://www.test.com/test/rest/v1");

Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(roots, xmlStreamWriter);
```

Comment: Look into this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979762/adding-namespaces-to-root-element-of-xml-using-jaxb

Comment: Hope it answers your question.

Comment: After following the answer i am getting `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/test/rest/v1"` instead of just `xmlns="http://www.test.com/test/rest/v1"`. Any clue why it's happening?